# Autofill the months as we do for days of the week

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-auto-fill

When you type let's say Monday and Tuesday to the 2 cells in the same column back to back (i.e. Monday to A1, Tuesday to A2), when you drag it with auto-fill option, it would fill in the other days itself (like Wednesday to A3, Thursday to A4 etc). How can we do it for Months? Not the numbers as a date (i.e. 1/1/2019, 2/1/2019), not as the number of the months (i.e. 1,2,3), but as January (or Jan), February, March etc.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Cause on my Office Professional Plus 2013 it worked fine to complete month name as well as days of week the way you described.

Comment: False alarm :) I don't know why it didn't work the last time I tried but yes it works as you said Ronaldo. When it didn't work, maybe it has something to do if the file is brand new or you try to do it on a cell or adjacent cell which has a date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may already have this. If not, you can get the instructions by search "create custom list" within excel. Follow the instructions and add your own custom list.
[image]